# Proper way to create MySql interface in Go

Tags: mysql, go, interface

I am working on connecting my application to MySql. The code is structured the following way, which works, but looks a little odd to me. Is this the right pattern to follow?

I have saved my Db related things in a separate file, which looks like this:

```
var DatabaseObject MySqlDatabase

type IMySqlDatabase interface {
    ConnectToDb() MySqlDatabase
    GetDb() MySqlDatabase
}

type MySqlDatabase struct{
    Db *sql.DB
}

func (MySqlDatabase) ConnectToDb(connectionString string){
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)

    _ = db.Ping()

    DatabaseObject = MySqlDatabase{Db: db}
}

    func (MySqlDatabase) GetDb() *sql.DB{
    return DatabaseObject.Db
}
```

As such I can connect to the database the following way:

```
infrastructureMySql.DatabaseObject.ConnectToDb(connectionString)
```

Which I find odd. Is there any sense of having an interface in the first place? If I didn't have it I could simply use the **sql.DB* as a global variable. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally like to follow this guide by Ben Johnson when creating db:
[See 3. Wrap types for application-specific context](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091)

This article mentions that we can provide an abstract layer here by interacting with the interface and so you don't need to leak these details in the application layer. 
You mentioned that you would like to perform queries and other commands so you can draw up an interface regarding those commands like so:

```
type Mysql struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

// Wrap a new connection into the MySql struct
func NewMysql() (*Mysql, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open(...)
    return &Mysql{ db }, err
}

func (m *Mysql) GetUsers(...) ([]User, error) {}
func (m *Mysql) CreateUsers(...) (User, error) {}

type UserStore interface {
   GetUsers func(...) []User, error)
   CreateUsers func(...) (User, error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this approach. I'm wondering how should I call the UserStore functions and where should I store the Mysql object. Is it okay to keep it as a global variable? If I just return it to my main function, it needs to be passed a thousand times. What do you think? Thanks again :)

Comment: You could use a "Handler" type approach where you have a type that implements the interface. Then you can just call something like: `handler.UserStore.GetUsers()`

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely incorrect:

- `MySqlDatabase` does not implement `IMySqlDatabase`, so it would not work if you actually tried to use the interface
- You're not actually using the interface

And has style issues:

- The interface returns concrete types, which defeats the purpose
- The interface appears to be a factory of itself? Or something? It's unclear what the interface or the concrete type are really supposed to be/do
- Interfaces in Go should not be named `IThing`, that's C#
- You appear to have type methods which modify globals which is going to be extremely unexpected to anyone using them

Comment: Thank you, my goal would be to have a globally accessible Db object, that I can use in queries and commands. Would it be better to connect to the Db separately at each request and close the connection afterwards?

Comment: @Jani the docs on [`sql.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) state *"The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB. "*. Note that the returned `*sql.DB` is not *a* connection, it is a *pool* of connections.

Comment: @mkopriva, thank you, then global variable it is :)